# Unable to find libPluginProtocol.jar while integrating Facebook plugin with Cocos2d-x android on windows

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to integrate facebook using Plugin-x in cocos2d-x v3.5. I followed the following steps:

1. cd to MyProject/cocos2d/plugin/tools/
2. ./publish.sh - on cygwin all the plugins get published one by one, for eg consider this Flurry trace

   ```
   atarget dir is /Users/Shivam/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/publish/plugins/flurry
   android project dir is /Users/Shivam/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/plugins/flurry/proj.android

   Publish plugin for android
   ~/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/plugins/flurry/proj.android ~/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/tools ~/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/tools

   BUILD SUCCESSFUL
   Total time: 0 seconds

   BUILD FAILED
   /Users/Shivam/Documents/Gautam/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:542: Unable to resolve project target 'android-7'

   Total time: 0 seconds
   cp: /Users/Shivam/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/plugins/flurry/proj.android/bin/*.jar: No such file or directory
   ~/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/tools 
   ~/Documents/Gautam/FinalWorkingApp/cocos2d/plugin/tools
   ```

All the plugins get published in the similar manner. I don't have android API 7, because of which it is failing, so can this be the reason my libpluginProtocol.jar is not getting generated?

I see a proper structure under under MyProject/cocos2d/plugin/publish/plugins

I also used gameDevGuide.sh and selected facebook.
Still I don't see libPluginProtocol.jar and libPluginFacebook.jar.

Please help. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer. the library gets generated only when you have all the Android APIs viz, 7,8,10,17 and 19 apart from your own target APIs